# Blazor CascadingValue programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, webassembly

I created a own base Component and i want all my Page components inhertis from this base Component

```
public class BaseComponent : ComponentBase
{
    // ...
}
```

a Page Component:

```
@page "/apage"
@inherits BaseComponent
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div>
        <MyOtherComponent />
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
```

In MyOtherComponent i want to do:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public BaseComponent BaseComponent { get; set; }
```

Till here all works. But i want to improve and i want every page component should make `CascadingValue Value="this"` because every page which inherits from BaseComponent should give the BaseComponent reference to all child components which need the reference.

So a Page Component should be like this:

```
@page "/apage"
@inherits BaseComponent
<div>
    <MyOtherComponent />
</div>
```

And the logic for CascadingValue Value="this" should be moved into BaseComponent.
How i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution:

I created a service class with interface.

```
public interface IStateService
{
    bool Pening { get; set; }
}
public class StateService : IStateService
{
    public bool Pening { get; set; }
}
```

And added it in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStateService, StateService>();
```

Than i injected it into BaseComponent.cs

```
[Inject]
public IStateService StateService { get; set; }
```

And all other components like MyOtherComponent can inject it too if they need.